# Is it possible for Multiple Consumers to consume same message on a Pulsar Topic?

Tags: language-agnostic, apache-pulsar

Let's say for that one has a Pulsar Producer for a persistent topic `topic1` (namespace and tenant are not relevant for the question).

And let's say we have multiple consumers for the same topic (`topic1`) with different subscription names.

Is it possible to configure the consumers to receive same message?  So for example if message `msg1` is sent to the topic both `consumer1` and `consumer2` receive this message?

Both consumers and producer are written in Java but programming language is not important.

**Clarification**

The current behavior observed with multiple subscriptions on the same topic with multiple subscriptions is that each of the subscribers do not receive all messages that have been published to the topic.  I need to receive all messages from the topic.

Comment: Both of the consumers should receive all of the messages as long as they are created and establish their subscriptions BEFORE the producer sends any messages. FYI, a subscription delivers all messages published to the topic AFTER it is created, it doesn't go back a deliver previously published messages on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use multiple subscriptions on the topic.

I wrote a blog post on this exact topic: ["Subscriptions: Multiple Groups of Consumers on a Pulsar Topic"](https://kafkaesque.io/subscriptions-multiple-groups-of-consumers-on-pulsar-topic/).

Comment: Above link is broken, should be updated to [this link](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/11/subscriptions-multiple-groups-consumers-pulsar-topic)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is possible for multiple consumers to receive the same copy of messages from a topic. Subscription determines how messages are delivered to consumers. What you need is each consumer has own `Exclusive` subscription. Here is the code example in Java.

```
String topicName = "your-tenant/namespace/topic1"
Consumer consumer1 = client.newConsumer()
            .topic(topicName)
            .subscriptionName("my-subscription1")
            .subscriptionInitialPosition(SubscriptionInitialPosition.Earliest)
            .subscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Exclusive)
            .subscribe();

// create another consumer
Consumer consumer2 = client.newConsumer()
            .topic(topicName)
            .subscriptionName("my-subscription2")
            .subscriptionInitialPosition(SubscriptionInitialPosition.Earliest)
            .subscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Exclusive)
            .subscribe();

// two consumers receive messages in alternate from the same topic
while (true) {
        Message msgFromConsumer1 = consumer1.receive();

        Message msgFromConsumer2 = consumer2.receive();
}
```